# How can i call a url from command line with out prccessing time

Tags: php, centos, exec

I need to call a url (cannot be path) from command line which should run in background 
I need to call a a page from php exec function , that page will take 10+ seconds to load so i just need to call that page so that the load will not affect to he user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to use fsockopen() to open a url to exec
here is the [full tutorial](http://robert.accettura.com/blog/2006/09/14/asynchronous-processing-with-php/)

Answer (score 3):

PHP doesn't support multithreading, but you can perform background tasks (only on Linux/*nix) by using [fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php). You'd use it like this:

```
// some logic here
if( pcntl_fork() == 0 ) {
    // initialise cURL here
    curl_exec("http://the.uri.I/want/toCall");
    exit(0);
}
// continue with your original processing
```

Answer (score 0):

By "call a URL from command line", I assume you will execute `curl`. In that using `at` could do the trick:

```
`echo "curl yourUrl.com/path" | at now`;
```